# Can I get timestamps for each step in cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

In cucumber past, I seem to remember an option to get the time it took for each step to complete

```
    And I navigate to a widget with widget form
    #features/step_definitions/common_sd.rb:26
  ### STEP COMPLETED   9.634963s
```

Thinking this functionality went away from cucumber, my work around was to add time stamp functionality to every snippet which feels clunky

```
 st = Time.now
 ...
 step_end(st)
```

and

```
 def step_end(st)
   puts "### STEP COMPLETED   #{(Time.now - st)}s"
 end
```

I could use the `env.rb` if I wanted universal hooks for the beginning and end of each scenario, but not steps as far as I can tell.

I can craft some sort of global step wrapper that adds the time metrics and calls each step.

Any ideas on the most elegant way to get time to complete for a step?

Comment: Have you looked at the already available hooks cucumber provides? Specifically [`AfterStep`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#step-hooks)

Comment: Yeah, but that would still be a line added to every scenario.  If I know going in that I want time to run on every step going forward, I'd really like to write the global command once, or find that elusive cucumber flag ```cucumber --timestamp features\tests\```

Answer (score 1):

This is copy-paste from my **features/support/env.rb**. I quit using cucumber years ago and hence I can’t provide a sophisticated answer, since I have almost everything forgotten, but I hope this snippet might led you towards right direction:

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'bundler/setup'
require 'rspec/expectations'

MAX_SCENARIOS = 10
scenario_times = {}

Around() do |scenario, block|
  start = Time.now
  block.call
  sc = if scenario.respond_to?(:scenario_outline)
         scenario.scenario_outline
       else
         scenario
       end
  t = scenario_times["#{sc.feature.file}::#{scenario.name}"] = Time.now - start
  # puts "### STEP COMPLETED #{t}s"
end

# print top 10 sorted by execution time
at_exit do
  max_scenarios = if scenario_times.size > MAX_SCENARIOS
                    MAX_SCENARIOS
                  else
                    scenario_times.size
                  end

  puts '—'*20 + "  top #{max_scenarios} slowest  " + '—'*20
  sorted_times = scenario_times.sort { |a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] }
  sorted_times[0..max_scenarios - 1].each do |key, value|
    puts "#{value.round(5)}  #{key}"
  end 
end
```